# Creating a fixed header with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Using flexbox I'm trying to create a fixed header that includes only two elements and these elements are as far away from each other as possible. I cannot seem to get this to work with `justify-content: space-between`.

I expected this CSS code to work but the elements are just sitting next to each other.

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<header>
<a>
  LOGO
  </a>
  <a>
  MENU
  </a>
</header>
```

Comment: the duplicate is a general one that will make you understand how to use each property for each axis (and many more)

Answer (score 4):

You almost had it. Use `justify-content`, not `align-content`.

**Edit:** As a commenter pointed out, `left: 0` is needed as well to truly keep each flex child pinned to their respective corners. Another option to beat the default browser margins would be to instead add `html, body { margin: 0; }`.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a>
  LOGO
  </a>
  <a>
  MENU
  </a>
</header>
```

Comment: the width is needed because the element is set position:fixed

Comment: You're right. I had removed that rule, mistakenly. Replaced!

Comment: @AndyHoffman you can add `left: 0` too... now there's some *margin* to the left side and the content overflows a bit to the right